# Command Line to retreive CyberPanel/Snappymail admin dashboard password on Ubuntu Virtual Machine

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, amazon-lightsail, cyber-panel

I recently purchased a VPS with amazon lightsail and I installed cyberpanel. As I am setting up my websites and email server I realized that I was not able to send out emails but can receive them just fine. I later found out that amazon blocks the ports on EC2 instances. So in order to use a work around I have to attach my SMTP server from AWS SES into the SMTP settings in the admin dashboard of the SnappyMail webmail dashboard. But In order to log in as admin to access it I need a password that I dont have. Since I installed cyberpanel on this Ubuntu 20.04 instance I was hoping that it would be a command line that I can type in to see what the current password is or maybe even reset or change it. Please help me

I tried to look it up on youtube but I kept getting videos that referred to rainloop. And all though it looks the same they are different softwares and I cant access it the way that I was shown in the 2 videos that I found

Answer (score 0):

Run `nano /usr/local/lscp/cyberpanel/rainloop/data/_data_/_default_/admin_password.txt`

you will find the Password of snappymail

then (Ctrl+X) to exit NANO edit